# Assining permission to www folder

Tags: permissions, apache2

Very new to Linux (Ubuntu). So getting lost each moment where this time I just installed Apache and trying to create file in `www` folder. But it is giving permission error.

Now I don't even know how to reach to the `www` folder in `terminal`. Embarrassing but just can't find a way.

Can anyone help me to set permission for this folder? Also how to reach to the folder in terminal.

Comment: I assume the default `www` folder resides in `/var/www/`.. May I ask; as to why are you trying to create another whilst having one in default? Also, what is the error error you're getting when trying to create &  exactly are you trying to create?

Comment: @AzkerMohamed thanks for reply, Actually I am trying to learn Ubuntu and so Installed `apache2` and `php` just now and trying to create `inddex.php` for `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` just to check. Now I am wonder. Is not `www` folder where we create a site?

Comment: You've to place it in `/var/www` folder where you'll see an `index` file.. replace an index file (or edit the current).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default **permission** is `drwxr-xr-x`

The default **owner** is `root`

To reach **www** directory in terminal :

```
cd /var/www
```

To change permission :

```
sudo chmod 755 /var/www     ( this is the default)
```

To change the owner :

```
sudo chown root:root /var/www (this is the default)
```

To create directory in /var/www :

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/nameyouwant
```

to change the owner of the new directory :

```
 sudo chown username:usernamegroup /var/www/nameyouwant -R
```

Note you can use -R option for **recursive**

Comment: For the latter bit, `sudo chown -R YOUR-USERNAME:YOUR-USERNAME /var/www` may work better...

Comment: Now I have big confusion after reading few docs. Where to store development files? in `/var/www/` folder or in `home/user/public_html/` if in `public_html` than I afraid I don't have that folder

Comment: in /var/www so you can access the by your browser at localhost after installing apache

Comment: Okay I used @Wilf command and I am now able to create file through terminal. Just one question. DO I need to run this command every time I restart the machine?

Comment: @pixelngrain - no, the command has just changed the owner of the files to your user & group. For developing stuff, it is easy to have it in your home directory, and then to copy the needed bits over to `/var/www` when you want to test it.

Comment: I see thanks to everyone.. Just a matter of time with Ubuntu. Anyone can suggest me any best docs or site where I can learn all this tricks and command?

Comment: I would not recommend taking ownership of `www` directory or the contents resides inside it. Instead I would advise to add the necessary user to the `www-data` group (which is the current group holding permission to the directory). To achieve that, user can execute `sudo useradd -G www-data username`

Answer (score 0):

The default www folder used by apache lives in `/var/www`

However, it is owned by the apache user: `www-data`. To be able to place files in that folder, you can temporarily become the apache user: type `sudo su www-data` (within a terminal). Whatever commands you issue on that console will be done as the apache user, until you type `exit`

Or, even better, you can copy things over and then change them to belong to the apache user: `sudo cp myfiles /var/www && sudo chown /var/www/myfiles www-data:www-data` will do the trick (where *myfiles* are the files you want to place in the /var/www folder).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Just wonder to know in which folder I should place all site content? Sorry about very basic question but first time using Ubuntu as well as manually installing apache and php.

Comment: To downvoter: please explain why you downvote, so that I may fix the answer.

Comment: @pixelngrain it will work fine if you place it under /var/www. However, you can place it anywhere that the apache server will look for it. You define those things in the configuration files found in /etc/apache2/ (they are not too hard to read). For now, I would leave them in /var/www, changing permissions as needed.