# How to add a user in only particular directory and no permission to another directory linux

Tags: command-line, permissions, apache2, users, user-management

My Root access is /Var/www/html
and i create giz folder under html and i need a access for this particular folder for jslpsgiz user
and this user can not accessing in other path and folder.
Path /var/www/html/giz/  ---- For jslpsgiz user and

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assining permission to www folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423133/assining-permission-to-www-folder)

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Your question as currently written doesn't appear to relate directly to the Ubuntu OS, but to permissioning of an Apache web server. While you might find a solution here, you would likely be better served over on the [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).